# package.json path don't exist after expo start was run

Tags: node.js, terminal, expo, package.json

I get the below information in the terminal once I run `expo start` in the terminal. Before `expo start` I have run:

1. repository was coppied into the folder
2. npm install -g yarn
3. npm install --global expo-cli

All the above processes went successfully.

[snipp from VS Code terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NS87b.png)
[image: Screenshot of the error message]

Comment: can you please add the file structure of your project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run the project from package.json.

1. click the right button on package.json
2. Run in console integrated (Open the console)
3. Now, you can run it.

If you don't have created the package.json You can run
**npm install**